# Multiple Monitors on both HDMI and DisplayPort

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have a Tower Computer with 2 graphics cards. Both of the cards have 1 HDMI and 1 DisplayPort. Which means the computer got a total of 2 HDMI and 2 DisplayPort(S)

Would i be able to connect all the ports to different monitors at the same time?
Like, the 2 HDMI to 2 seperate minitors, and the 2 DisplayPort(s) to 2 seperate monitors, to get a total of 4 monitors on one computer?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which graphics cards do you use, do they have SLI and are they SLI connected?

Comment: If you have one graphics card with 2 outputs, and 2 outputs directly from the motherboard, then it is important to know this too.

Comment: It saw already been solved in the answer below. But thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes, but you need to look in your GPU's manual/specification to see if it supports outputting on HDMI and DisplayPort simultaneously (usually they do). 
In some special cases you will need to also disable things like CrossFireX in driver's settings.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! Im not much of a computer genius, so i don't know what to look for in the GPU

Comment: Could you provide your GPU model?

Comment: Im not quite sure what exactly the GPU is. But i would guess that it has something to do with your graphics card?

Comment: GPU = short name for graphic card (graphic processing unit)

Comment: I've got 2 x (SLI) MSI GEFORCE GTX 1070 8GB ( Copy and Pasted )

I know i said 1 HDMI and 1 DisplayPort before, but the question remains the same ( This one has 3 DP and 1 HDMI each )

Comment: So it means that it IS possible to connect atleast 3 monitors?

Comment: 1070 definitely supports 4 monitors on single card.

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much for your assistance. I really appretiate it +1